# How to set SOA Expire Value?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone, soa-record

I ran my domain through intoDNS and the report returned a warning saying

```
Your SOA EXPIRE number is: 3600000. That is NOT OK
```

So I've been looking to change the value ever since. You wouldn't believe it but I couldn't find one place that tells where or how to change the value of SOA Expire. I found out the recommended range is 2-4 weeks but no clue as to where to go to change it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What dns server are you using?  Normally the SOA details are defined in the zone file or equivalent type file for your server.

Comment: I'm not sure. I haven't configured any DNS servers. Can you find it out with my domain? Its [https://bwdmedia.net](https://bwdmedia.net) or a [summary from Network Tools](http://network-tools.com/default.asp?prog=express&host=bwdmedia.net)

Comment: In many cases mentioning the actual domain name is essential for the community to be able to help diagnose DNS issues. Thank you for doing that.

Comment: If DNS server is not managed by you - contact your hosting company

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `expire` field in a SOA record is the upper limit, in seconds, that your secondary name servers are allowed to use the data before it expires for lack of getting a refresh.

You normally do want this to be rather large, and the value of 3600000 seconds (about 42 days) comes straight out of [RFC 1033](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1033).

There is no real need to change it. Most DNS/hosting providers don't allow you to edit SOA records anyway either, with good reason as it determines how **their DNS infrastructure** will operate.

You would only need to worry about the [values in the SOA record](https://serverfault.com/a/555241/37681) if you operate your own name servers, which doesn't appear to be the case.

```
dig soa bwdmedia.net +multiline

bwdmedia.net.       86400 IN SOA ns.inmotionhosting.com. exploitrip.outlook.com. (
                2016091000 ; serial
                86400      ; refresh (1 day)
                7200       ; retry (2 hours)
                3600000    ; expire (5 weeks 6 days 16 hours)
                86400      ; minimum (1 day)
                )
```

That shows that among other that your primary DNS server is `ns.inmotionhosting.com.` and your DNS is probably managed by that hosting company.

Comment: These are most likely managed by the hosting company. Thanks for letting me know. I'll have a chat with them

Comment: I have a glued ns that points to the domain itself. So I am my own nameserver. The only DNS server installed I have are the DNS controls from PLESK.

Comment: Nit: The RFC standard you quoted suggests "A minimum of at least a day is a good value here (86400)" not 3600000. The value you're quoting was just an example.